# Convert ArrayList/ Hash map to Resultset

Tags: java, mysql, cassandra

I have a Cassandra resulset which I am trying to convert into MySql resultset.

I have converted the Cassandra resultset into Arraylist. I am now trying to convert it into SQL resultset. I am unable to convert Arraylist to SQL resultset. Alternatively I was trying to convert Cassandra resultset into Hashmap and then convert into SQL resultset. But no luck on it too.

Please let me know if the above thing is possible or theirs any other way out.

Comment: Why do you need that? I am surprised anyone would prefer that.

Comment: I have reports which is generated using MySQL Resulset. I am now trying to generate the same reports using Cassandra. So with minimal of changes to existing code I was trying to do the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL ResultSet is a huge interface, with many many methods. But I guess you're only actually using a few of them in your reports. So you could probably create an Adapter class, where all the unused methods simply throw an UnsupportedOperationException, and the other ones delegate to the Cassandra ResultSet. Something like this:

```
public CassandraResultSetAdapter implements java.sql.ResultSet {
    private final Iterator<Row> delegate;
    private Row currentRow;

    public CassandraResultSetAdapter(ResultSet cassandraResultSet) {
        this.delegate = cassandraResultSet.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() {
        if (delegate.hasNext()) { 
            return false;
        }
        else {
            this.currentRow = delegate.next();
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String columnName) {
        return currentRow.getString(columnName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getString(String columnIndex) { // starts at 1
        return currentRow.getString(columnIndex - 1); // starts at 0
    }

    ...
}
```